# Align equation multiple columns

Tags: equations, align

Is it possible to align an equation like this:

[image]

I tried this, but:

```
\begin{align*}
    & u_a(t) &= u_e(t) - u_{R1}(t) \\
    &        &= u_e(t) - R_1 \cdot i_1(t) = u_e(t) - R_1(i_2(t) + i_3(t)) \\
    &        &= u_e(t) - R_1 \cdot i_2(t) - R_1 \cdot i_3(t) \\
    &        &= u_e(t) - R_1 \cdot \frac{u_a(t)}{R_2} - R_1 \cdot C \cdot \ddt[t]{u_a(t)}\\
<=> & u_a(t) + u_a(t) \cdot \frac{R_1}{R_2} + C \cdot R_1 \ddt[t]{u_a(t)} = u_e(t) \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the `\dd` macro, please?

Comment: That's just for the derivation fraction df(x)/dx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For multiple alignments you can use `aligned` inside `align`.

```
\begin{align*}
    & \begin{aligned}
      u_a(t) &= u_e(t) - u_{R1}(t) \\
             &= u_e(t) - R_1 \cdot i_1(t) = u_e(t) - R_1(i_2(t) + i_3(t)) \\
             &= u_e(t) - R_1 \cdot i_2(t) - R_1 \cdot i_3(t) \\
             &= u_e(t) - R_1 \cdot \frac{u_a(t)}{R_2} - R_1 \cdot C \cdot 
    ddt[t]{u_a(t)}\\
    \end{aligned}\\
<=> & u_a(t) + u_a(t) \cdot \frac{R_1}{R_2} + C \cdot R_1 ddt[t]{u_a(t)} = u_e(t) \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]